# Fetch with URLSearchParams object - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a custom hook called useFetch:

```js
const useFetch = (url: string, method = 'get', queryParams: any) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    let queryString = url;
    if (queryParams) {
      queryString += '?' + queryParams;
    }
    // omitted try and catch construction for code readability
    const result = await fetch(queryString, method, queryParams);
    return await result.json();
  }, [url, method, queryParams]);
}
```

Component that uses `useFetch`:

```js
const { response, error } = useFetch(
  '/orders',
  'get',
  new URLSearchParams({
    limit: state.limit.toString(),
    offset: state.offset!.toString()
  }).toString()
);
```

If i pass `queryParams` as string, i'm not getting infinite re-render loops, because it's a primitive type `String`, but if i use:

```js
const { response, error } = useFetch(
  '/orders',
  'get',
  {
    limit: state.limit.toString(),
    offset: state.offset!.toString()
  }
);
```

And then change `useEffect` respectively:

```js
let queryString = url;
if (queryParams) {
  queryString += '?' + new URLSearchParams(queryParams).toString();
}
```

This causing re-renders, even if a `queryParams` won't change deeply, because `{} !== {}`, i can do this:

```js
const queryParamsRef = useRef(queryParams);
```

Then i won't get re-renders, because on every re-render it's the same object by reference, but as you noticed, i'm using state variables inside this `queryParams` object, so when the state changes, i won't get re-render, because `queryParamsRef` is still referenced to the previous object.

What's the best way to solve this issue? Is it ok to pass it just as string, like in my first codeblock?

Answer (score 0):

If possible the best would be to get the values without using the url's params but if necessary personally I use https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string with `window.location.search'.